# How to send and receive file with socket programming in java

Tags: java, sockets, session, server, client

Hello I have a problem with sending and receiving files through sockets in java

I've written 2 while in client and session class one for sending and one for receiving
program starts and send a request file from client to session then session receives it and creates it

after that session send response file to client and client receives it and creates it

when I remove 2nd "while"s in both client and session class , program works and client sends data and session receives it and create the file
but when I add 2nd "while"s again , program stuck and even last operation that I mentioned won't work

Server Class

```
public class Server {
public Server(int port) {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("New client connected" + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            Session clientSocket = new Session(client);
            new Thread(clientSocket).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Server server = new Server(5000);
}}
```

Session Class :

```
public class Session implements Runnable{
private Socket socket;
public Session(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}
public void run(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("RequestClient.txt");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Response.txt");
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        int count;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        while ((count = dataInputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        while ((count = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        dataOutputStream.close();
        dataInputStream.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Client Class :

```
public class Client {
    public Client (String address, int port) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            File requestFile = new File("Request.txt");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("ResponseServer.txt");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(requestFile);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((count = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            while ((count = dataInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            dataInputStream.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public static void main(String args[]){
    Client connectionService = new Client("127.0.0.1", 5000);
}}
```

Comment: also when I remove 1st "while"s , again program works

Comment: @AliasCartellano thanks , but I don't know how to run debugger for server client programs. could you please guide me more ?